# Generics in Java Comparator class. What is the exact type of T and U?

Tags: java, generics, comparator

Consider the two following methods. Their only difference is in their generic type declaration of Function<>

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparingT(
        Function<T, ? extends U> keyExtractor) <-- Check here! T instead of ? super T
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Let's say I have a `List<GamingComputer> = { ASUS, MSI }`, where `GamingComputer` extends `Computer`. Now, I want to sort them.

```
List.sort( comparing( Computer::getProperty ) )
```

**What is the type of T?**

My intuition: `T=GamingComputer`. `comparing()` takes in `keyExtractor`, whose type is `Function<Computer super GamingComputer, Property>`. Finally, `comparing()` returns `Comparator<GamingComputer>`.

This code, proving my intuition, compiles perfectly:

```
Function<Computer, Property> f1 = Computer::getProperty;
Comparator<GamingComputer> c1 = comparing(f1);
```

Now, by PECS, since `c1`, `c2` are being added to a collection/ constructor/ method, as long as the collection handles their parent class, it could handle any child class. That's the reason behind `<? super T>`.

As demonstrated in this code:

```
Function<Computer, Property> f2 = Computer::getProperty;
Comparator<GamingComputer> c2 = comparingT(f2); // FAILS to compile. Required Type: Comparator<GamingComputer>, Provided Comparator<Computer>
Comparator<Computer> c2 = comparingT(f2); // compiles successfuly
```

Since `f2` works with all `Computer`, it should be able to work with any `GamingComputer` as well. However, because we did not declare type as `<? super T>`, we are unable to construct a `Comparator` of `GamingComputers`.

Makes sense. Then...

```
Comparator<GamingComputer> c22 = comparingT(Computer::getProperty); // compiles successfuly... WT, excuse mi French, heck???
```

My guess: `comparingT()` with type `T=GamingComputer` forces a downcast on `keyExtractor`, which is `Computer::getProperty`. It forces all `Computers` to use `GamingComputer::getProperty`, which is probably not an issue, since `Comparator<GamingComputer>` does compare `GamingComputers`.

But, why does this NOT compile?

```
Function<Computer, Property> f22 = GamingComputer::getProperty;
```

The error is very peculiar:

Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context, which is probably a *bug* from Intellij

[Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context in java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200958/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-in-java-8-streams)

Still, when compiling:

```
java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    method getPart in class function.GamingComputer cannot be applied to given types
      required: no arguments
      found: function.Computer
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: "*why does this NOT compile?* `Function<Computer, Property> f22 = GamingComputer::getProperty;`" this LHS says it can take any Computer. It cannot. The RHS says it must take a GamingComputer

Comment: @Michael Then it brings me to my previous question, why does c22 compile? c22 uses my modded comparingT() method, which has a fixated T across the method. However, we can clearly see that c22 consists of both Computer and GamingComputer.

Comment: Please don't write two questions in one post. I have edited to only include the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intuition: `T=GamingComputer`

Your intuition is correct.

---

> Why does `Comparator<GamingComputer> c22 = comparingT(Computer::getProperty);` compile?

This is because unlike instances of functional interfaces which are invariant, method references are covariant and contravariant. Using an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636482/method-reference-covariance-contravariance), you can do something like:

```
// in SomeClass
public static Integer function(Object o) {
    return 2;
}

// ...
Function<String, Object> function = SomeCLass::function;
```

Or using your classes, you can do:

```
Function<GamingComputer, Property> f = Computer::getProperty;
```

It's "as if" method references have `? super` on their parameters and `? extends` on the return types! The details of what works and what doesn't are specified in section [15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) of the Java Language Specification.

So for `c22`, `T` is still `GamingComputer`. The method reference `Computer::getProperty` can be converted to `Function<GamingComputer, Property>` it's a method reference.

This does not compile, even though `f2` "stores" `Computer::getProperty`:

```
Comparator<GamingComputer> c2 = comparingT(f2);
```

because `f2` is not a method reference itself. It is a variable.

> Why does `Function<Computer, Property> f22 = GamingComputer::getProperty;` not compile?

`f22` would be able to accept any kind of `Computer`, since it accepts `Computer`. If you give `f22` another kind of computer (not `GamingComputer`), `GamingComputer.getProperty` certainly would not be able to handle that, would it?